# Android Studio - 4.2.2 :: Run Bundle (Install APK from Bundle) - INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-studio, build, bundle

Out of no where, testing locally the Bundle's asset files, this error is now appearing:

```
> 07/23 10:15:12: Launching 'Bundle' on samsung SM-T510.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION
List of apks:
[0] '.../out/base-en.apk'
[1] '.../out/large_assets-master.apk'
[2] '.../out/base-master.apk'
[3] '.../out/base-hdpi.apk'
[4] '.../out/base-armeabi_v7a.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'
Retry
```

I have tried to following:

- Clean & Rebuild
- Uninstall app from device
- Reinstall latest version Android Studio
- Restart Mac mini x5 times
- Restart device ~3 times
- Revert back to previous Git branch

I can change the Run Config to App which works perfectly, but does not allow me to test feature with the asset files.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Please see attached screenshots of both Run Configs

App Run Config (Working perfectly)
[Run Config - App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFtAU.png)

Bundle Run Config (Not Working out of no-where)
[Run Config - Bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDOBO.png)

Answer (score 0):

for me change to other device, it works.

the error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION

List of apks:
[0] '/myProject/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/aabRelease/out/base-arm64_v8a_2.apk'
[1] '/myProject/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/aabRelease/out/base-master_2.apk'
[2] '/myProject/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/aabRelease/out/base-mdpi.apk'
[3] '/myProject/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/aabRelease/out/base-zh.apk'
[4] '/myProject/build/intermediates/extracted_apks/aabRelease/out/module_game-master.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```